# Visual Studio 2015 Brace and Parenthesis autocomplete

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

When I make a new node web app project, in my `js` files when type a `(`, it doesn't insert a pair of `()`. When I type the keyword `function`, it doesn't autocomplete with a pair of braces `{}` or square brackets `[]`.

When I make a new Visual C# Asp.NET Project and add `js` files to it, the auto-completion works fine. The same is true when making a `js` file in a blank solution, so the behavior seems distinct to nodejs projects.

I've already checked the `Automatic Brace Completion` option under

```
Options > Text Editor > Javascript
```

The behavior is the same whether I'm using `node.js tools 1.1` or `1.2 RC`.
However, the auto-completion works fine in `node projects` for `VS2013`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem after reading the info here:

> https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/1142

It was fixed by going to

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > Node.js > IntelliSense

and changing intellisense mode to ECMAScript 5. Basically, Nodejs tools' editors' es6 intellisense is powered by typescript, and can't do automatic brace completion.